# Eclipse classpath not showing IVY dependency tree. Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, eclipse, ivy, ivyde

For some reasons outside my control the project I am working on uses ivy.xml for buildtime dependencies and we have a separate runtime.xml ivy file for use when running up a service in eclipse.  This is done by created a new runtime configuration and then adding the runtime.xml via the Advanced option on the Classpath tab of the launcher.

This works fine and the application runs up without any problems.  The one major annoyance, is that having added runtime.xml the classpath view of the launch configuration just displays Ivy and does not provide a tree structure view like you get in the Project Explorer view (see screenshot below).  This makes it impossible to quickly view the resolved dependencies for the runtime configuration.

We are on eclipse Kepler and I appreciate it is an older version, but was wondering whether:

- There is a workaround?
- This may have been rectified in a later version?

Comment: where is the screenshot mentioned in `see screenshot below` ?

Comment: Apologies.  No where to upload screenshot.